# Function to create a connection list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

Let assume that i have a list of connections between nodes like this:

```
input = {1 <-> 10, 2 <-> 3, 4 <-> 5, 6 <-> 7, 8 <-> 9};
```

The order of elements in a list and in a pair is not important.
So the input above should be treat the same as `{3 <-> 2, 1 <-> 10, 4 <-> 5, 6 <-> 7, 8 <-> 9}`. 
 
I'm trying to build a function `myfunc[input_, remove_]` which generates the new list depending the list remove as follows. 
I'll try to give some example: 
If `remove == {1 <-> 2}` then the return output is `{3 <-> 10, 4 <-> 5, 6 <-> 7, 8 <-> 9}` as now nodes `{1, 2}` are shorten and removed. 
 
And `remove` could have more then one element, for example: 
If `remove == {1 <-> 2, 5 <-> 6}` then nodes `{1, 2}, {5, 6}` are shorten and removed so the output is `{3 <-> 10, 4 <-> 7, 8 <-> 9}`. 
It's boring to do this manually so I'm looking for some quick way to accomplish this.

Here is an image to make it easier to understand:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `Complement`?

Comment: @Syed I know this function but not sure how it is used here.

Comment: Please ignore my comment. It was due to lack of understanding of the problem that you have now clarified.

Answer (score 5):

With some work, you can use the [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) functionality: First, converting & visualizing your input:

```
input = {1 <-> 10, 2 <-> 3, 4 <-> 5, 6 <-> 7, 8 <-> 9};

g = Graph[input, VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Above], 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Red, 
  VertexStyle -> Directive[Red, EdgeForm@None], EdgeStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

(note that `Graph[input]` would be enough, the rest is just styling)

The function to do the removal:

```
remove[g_, edges_List] := Fold[remove, g, edges]
remove[g_, edge_] := SimpleGraph@VertexReplace[
   EdgeAdd[g, edge],
   # -> First@VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g, #], Except[#]] & /@ 
    Flatten[List @@ edge]
   ]

remove[g, {1 <-> 2}]
```

[image]

```
remove[g, {1 <-> 2, 5 <-> 6}]
```

[image]

The idea of the function is:

- Add the additional edges, so it's easier to tell what will be connected afterwards using [`EdgeAdd`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeAdd.html)
- Get the neighbors of the vertices to be removed using [`NeighborhoodGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeighborhoodGraph.html).
- Finally, remove the vertices by replacing them with the first neighboor using [`VertexReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexReplace.html)
- The resulting graph will have self-loops, which we can clean using [`SimpleGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SimpleGraph.html)

Comment: Nice but it doesn't work for this case.
```input1 = {1 <-> 10, 2 <-> 3, 4 <-> 5, 6 <-> 7, 8 <-> 9}; 
g = Graph[input1, VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Above], VertexLabelStyle -> Red, 
    VertexStyle -> Directive[Red, EdgeForm[None]], EdgeStyle -> Black]; 
remove[g, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4}]```
I expect the output to be `{5 <-> 10, 9 <-> 8, 7 <-> 6}` rather than the output above.

Comment: @hana  Please see the updated answwr dor a fixed version

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[showGraph, ellipseLayout, remVertices];
showGraph[g_List] := Graph[Graph[Union @@ g, UndirectedEdge @@@ g]
  , VertexLabels -> "Name"
  , VertexCoordinates -> ellipseLayout[Length@(Union @@ g), {2, 1}]
  , VertexStyle -> Red
  , EdgeStyle -> Black
  ]
```

From one of the pages I visited in the docs:

```
ellipseLayout[n_, {a_, b_}] := 
 Table[{a Cos[2 Pi/n u], -b Sin[2 Pi/n u]}, {u, 1, n}]

remVertices[g_List, v_List] := 
 FlattenAt[#, 2] &@({Catenate@First@#, Last@#} &@
    Sort[GatherBy[g /. Thread[Rule[v, Nothing]], Length[#] < 2 &]])
```

---

To start with:

```
g0 = Partition[Range[10], 2, 1, {1, 1}][[{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}]]
```

> {{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}, {10, 1}}

For removing one vertex:

```
g1 = remVertices[g0, {1, 2}]
```

> {{3, 10}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}}

For removing more vertices contained in `v`:

```
v = {{1, 2}, {5, 6}};
g2 = Fold[remVertices[#1, #2] &, g0, v]
```

[image]

Comment: This is good that it generates correct result for `input = {{1, 10}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}}` and `remove = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` but the code looks quite complicated.

Comment: When I get around to learning about built-in graph functionality, I will appreciate it even more.

Comment: What does the GatherBy do there? Sublists are also lists with 2 elements (2 nodes) so it doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: Once the vertex is cut, it leaves a `{_}` list amongst other `{_,_}` lists . So I `GatherBy` the length.